# How can I use a QWidget derived component from a shared library on a Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, shared-libraries, qwidget

I'm doing some experimentation with Qt on the Mac just now but I can't get my widget to show up in my application.

I've used Qt on Windows before and to do this I would just reference the dll and promote a widget to my own class, using the appropriate header file. I've tried the same on Mac but just get a blank screen.

The steps that I went through were to build the library (which gives me several files, *.dylib, *.1.dylib, *.1.0.dylib and *.1.0.0.dylib) and use the "Add Library..." function on my main application project. I'm not sure what all of these different dylibs are for but I have tried copying all of them into /usr/lib and the Contents/Frameworks folder inside my application bundle.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be going wrong and the key differences between doing this simple test on Windows and Mac?

Thanks,
Alan

**Edit: Added code for project file**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-10-02T19:59:44
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TestApp
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-TestLibrary
Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_clang_64bit-Debug/release/ -lTestLibrary
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-TestLibrary
Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_clang_64bit-Debug/debug/ -lTestLibrary
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-TestLibrary-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_clang_64bit-Debug/ 
lTestLibrary

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../TestLibrary
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../TestLibrary
```

Comment: How do you link the library? (Show the .pro file, assuming you use qmake). And how do you instantiate it? If linking or loading fails, it will fail at startup latest, before the "blank screen".

Comment: I've added my code for the .pro file but I have just realised that I was doing something a bit silly... my test widget was not large enough to show its contents (just a button). Now that I've resized the widget, I no longer get the blank screen. Thanks for your help, you convinced me that the library was being loaded properly and put me in the right direction.